# java/ecplise: org.apache.commons.lang.math not resolved after added to build path

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, math

I am trying to use `NumberUtils` from apache commons math jar.

I downloaded the apache math commons zip here: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi
I pasted the commons-math3-3.6-javadoc.jar into my project and when to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries (Tab)  and clicked "Add JARs.." then selected the commons-math jar, hit apply, and ok.

When I import `import org.apache.commons.lang.math;`, ecplipse complains and states that `"org.apache.commons.lang"` cannot be resolved. What gives?

Here is screenshot:
https://app.box.com/s/22y4etke4kwro1q4mcoxazew76djg2u3

Comment: What happens if you try with ctrl + shift + o ?

Comment: The import org.apache.commons.lang3 cannot be resolved still

Comment: Why the "javadoc" jar? Does that even contain code (or just the javadocs?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html) is not apart of commons-math3, it is part of commons-lang3.

You need to download [commons.lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) instead, in order to use it.